# Check if .NET dynamic assembly is transient or persisted

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

When System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder is created, it can be persisted (initialized with AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save and similar) or transient (AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run oand similar). I'm going to create ModuleBuilder for assembly builder I have as input. But persisted module can't be created for transient assembly, so I have to check the status of assembly before module creation. How can I do this? The snippet is:

```
public ModuleBuilder Handle(AssemblyBuilder assembly, string name)
{
    if (assembly.IsPersisted) // IsPersisted is a kind of property I'm looking for
    {
        return assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name, name + ".dll");
    }
    else
    {
        return assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name);
    }
}
```

I can get assembly status by accessing its internal fields using reflection, so this is not an answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Just a guess, but what does assembly.CodeBase give you. IIRC it is the path the exe or dll file on disk. If it's not persisted that might give a clue.

Comment: Why are you creating modules separately from assemblies? You almost always want to have exactly one module in each assembly.

Comment: @simon at rcl: interesting idea, but in both cases I get NotSupportedException.

Comment: How about Assembly.Location? Apologies, that was the property I meant; not sure why I came up with CodeBase. If that doesn't help, it might be worth checking Codebase for your base exe file: if that doesn't return an exception then perhaps you could use that fact: Exception = not persisted?

Comment: @svick: Because of SRP. From the one side I have tons of assembly creation extensions (let it be N), that can be extended. From the other side - a lot of module creation routines (M). By passing AssemblyBuilder to these routines I can mix different emission strategies. If I put them together, I get N*M complexity instead of N+M.

Comment: @simon at rcl: Location is not supported too.

Comment: Check if you get the same error with persisted assemblies. If you don't, that would be one way to tell the difference.

Comment: I've checked for both. CodeBase, Location results in NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this exact situation - the only real way you can handle this, without passing in a state variable saying whether the assembly is to be persistable, is:

```
try
{
    return assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name, name + ".dll");
}
catch(NotSupportedException)
{
    return assembly.DefineDynamicModule(name);
}
```

Not pretty - but there's no real alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through reflection but you should wrap your concrete implementation to handle ominous exceptions since this relies on internal implementation such that there is no guarantee on API persistence.

```
if (assembly.IsDynamic)
{
        Type assemblyType = assembly.GetType();

        Type assemblyBuilderDataType = Assembly.GetAssembly(assemblyType)
                .GetType("System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderData");

        object assemblyBuilderData = assemblyType
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Single(fi => fi.FieldType == assemblyBuilderDataType)
                .GetValue(assembly);

        object assemblyBuilderAccess = assemblyBuilderDataType
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Single(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(AssemblyBuilderAccess))
                .GetValue(assemblyBuilderData);

        switch (assemblyBuilderAccess)
        {
                …
        }
}
```